# Problems with TFS first check-in (originally git project)

Tags: git, file, visual-studio-2012, tfs, service-reference

I ran into some problems with TFS. Basically I am attempting to check-in what was originally VS2010 project (WP7), but we have moved to using VS2012 since then. We used git for our version control and now want to migrate over to TFS.

What happened now is that the service references bug out somehow. The system is trying to check-in files that do not exist anymore. During the time of the development, the references were removed and replaced a few times. Now, it is trying to add files such as service141.xsd that do not exist. Furthermore, it does not seem to find the files that actually do contain the service reference information.

It also did not find some .gitignore file that no longer exist in the project. Does TFS scour through the git references somehow or where do these phantom files appear from. It is all peculiar to me since my method of migration was simple. 1) Open the Solution 2) Choose Add to Source Control.

TL;DR:
1) Phantom files appear when I try to add my solution to TFS (originally a git project). Why?
2) How do I get rid of these and add the actual ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS looks inside the .csproj files and the different service reference files to see which files need to be added to source control when you do the "Add solution to Sourcecontrol" step.

What I usually do is that I map the folder where my solution is located and then in the Source Control window use the <kbd>Add files and folders</kbd> button to add the files to sourcecontrol manually.

Then open the solution by doubleclicking the `sln` file directly in the Source Control Explorer and then when prompted, agree that Visual Studio updates the source control bindings for you.